# Line lengths calculation in combination with DEM

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins, dem, line

I am working in QGIS 2.18.0.

I have a problem regarding calculation of line lengths in combination with raster files, to be precise with DEM raster.

There is not a problem to calculate the line lengths (vector layer), but this calculation assumed the surface to be flat (or not?). By doing this that way I will calculate the length of the "cathetus", and I need the length of the "hypotenuse".

Is there any add-on or is there any formula to calculate the line length that incorporates the change in the altitude?

Comment: No one?

Is the question trivial or there is no solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a SAGA **Profiles from lines** tool, which is accessible from `QGIS Processing Toolbox | SAGA | Terrain Analysis - Profiles`.

[image]

Just give it your DEM (raster) and the line (vector) layers. It will return a new point layer (`Profiles`) in which attribute table you will find **DIST_SURF** field. It shows the cumulative length following DEM surface (your "hypotenuse") from the startpoint.

[image]