# Finding distance of line segment considering elevation in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, line, elevation, length

Normal distance can be easily computed in QGIS. But how can I do it for a line feature in 3d space, simply saying how to to find the line's distance noting its elevation.

For example, if a polyline feature represents a mountain then how to find distance from one end to another end with respect to Elevation?

Comment: Have you seen these articles [Different length measures in QGIS vs. ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321176/different-length-measures-in-qgis-vs-arcmap), [Planar vs Geodesic Area/Length?](https://community.esri.com/thread/230106-planar-vs-geodesic-arealength) and [Calculating Line Lengths and Statistics (QGIS3) | Step 4](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/calculating_line_lengths.html#calculating-line-lengths-and-statistics-qgis3).

Comment: Hi Taras and thank you for comment. Yes  all questions that you mentioned dealing with  line segment and finding distance in 2D plane .But here i wanted to know distance of line segment with elevation value.

Comment: Use DEM together with line in [SAGA Module Profiles from Lines](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.5/ta_profiles_4.html), see [Line lengths calculation in combination with DEM](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226968/line-lengths-calculation-in-combination-with-dem)

Comment: Thanks @Taras . I got result from the link that you mentioned.As there two distance exists in the attributes table. Is "DIST" is horizontal distance i.e is that normal distance between two points ?