# Measuring real distance in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, distance, vector-layer, measurements

I created the linear shapefile of an ancient Roman Road (via Flaminia), and I would like to compare the linear total distance with the real one: Roman engineers and Gromatici measured the roads with a machine (called Odometro), so the distance was influenced by the morphology.

Is there any instrument or tool in QGIS that is right for me? A friend of mine suggested I use the SAGA tool Profile from Lines, but it just creates an output points layer, that have the altitude in its attributes.

Comment: According to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226968/line-lengths-calculation-in-combination-with-dem thats what you use. The point layer has the cumulated distances.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line lengths calculation in combination with DEM](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226968/line-lengths-calculation-in-combination-with-dem)